# How do I install Chocolatey packages to another drive?

Tags: batch-file, chocolatey

I try to create a `.bat` file to automate the installation of several apps on a virtual machine. I use Chocolatey, but I have some difficulties for the installation of 3 apps: WinMerge, AdobeReader, and Paint.net

I want install these apps on another drive: `F:\Program Files`. I tried many commands, but none work.

```
> choco upgrade adobereader -y -ia "INSTALLDIR=""F:\Program Files\Adobe"""
> choco upgrade paint.net   -y -ia "INSTALLDIR=""F:\Program Files\paint.net"""
> choco upgrade winmerge    -y -ia "INSTALLDIR=""F:\Program Files\WinMerge"""
```

Paint.net are installed but in the C:\ drive. Winmerge extracts all the files on the F: drive, but isn't installed. And Adobe Reader fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally run these 3 commands and it's working.

```
choco upgrade adobereader -y -ia "INSTALLDIR=""F:\Program Files\Adobe"""
choco upgrade paint.net   -y -ia "TARGETDIR=""F:\Program Files\paint.net"""
choco upgrade winmerge    -y -ia "/DIR=""F:\Program Files\WinMerge"""
```

Answer (score 3):

It may help to understand first that there are different types of installers for Windows applications (in Chocolatey terminology we call them native installers) and they all accept that custom directory location with a different argument (and sometimes not at all if they are a homegrown custom version). We have this documented at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/GettingStarted#overriding-default-install-directory-or-other-advanced-install-concepts (which you've likely read based on your use of install arguments).

- MSI- it is either TARGETDIR or INSTALLDIR (as you have).
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusage) - `/D location with out quotes even if spaces` and must be passed as the very last argument.
- [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) - `/DIR="location"`

There is a reason we have https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/258 (with an original https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/32 from 2011) and a better reason we haven't implemented it yet - it's not exactly easy to do without knowing what the installer type is ahead of time. It is something that is planned, because it would be a huge win for everyone if we could support one switch to override them all.

Comment: I knew that there were different type of installers. The difficulty is to test which is used with the package. I can understand the difficulties to support all the installers

Comment: That's why we have the documentation - right now you are left to figure it out on your own. It's not optimal we know, but we've at least documented that it is up to you to determine it.